# How to select YAML mapping keys if they contain special keys

Tags: yaml, yq

I have a big YAMl file and i need to select all top mapping keys, that have other mapping key under them. It would be great if i could done parsing with yq, but other solutions are welcome too
For example, i have yaml file

```yaml
foo:
  bar:
    - "hello"
quz:
  bar:
    - "hi"
der:
  boo: true
```

and i need to select just `foo` and `bar` so my final yaml will look like this:

```yaml
foo:
  bar:
    - "hello"
quz:
  bar:
    - "hi"
```

I already tried something like this, it is do nothing
test.yaml contains example above

```
yq eval 'select(.[] | has("bar"))' test.yml
yq eval 'select(.[] | .bar != null)' test.yml
```

And i generally do not understand why using query without select gives me correct boolean output

```
yq eval '.[] | has("bar")' test.yml

true
true
false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `.[] | has("bar")` you get the booleans you would use in a wrapping `select` expression, but you're missing that `.[]` destructures the outer map (to generate the booleans) while `select` is still applied to the whole map (as it's in the outer context).

One way to achieve what you want is using `with_entries`, which takes a function that is provided access to each `.key` and `.value`, but retains the outer structure:

```bash
yq 'with_entries(select(.value | has("bar")))'
```

Another way could be to use the `pick` function, which takes a list of keys to keep. Generate that list by applying your original filter, and extracting each `key` from the matches (while using `map` instead of `.[]` to retain the array):

```bash
yq 'pick(map(select(has("bar")) | key))'
```

Both output:

```yaml
foo:
  bar:
    - "hello"
quz:
  bar:
    - "hi"
```

Tested with [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/) version v4.35.1. Note that since version v4.18.1, the `eval`/`e` command is the default, and can be omitted. (As an aside, the `with_entries` approach should also work as is using [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq/).)